# Join continuous PDF how to choose interval

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the joint pdf
$f_{x,y} (x,y) = 3/4 x $ if $0<x<y<2$

Now if I want to find the marginal pdfs $f_x $ and $ f_y$

How do I choose which interval to use when I integrate?

I know the answers are:

$f_x (x) = 3/4 x (2-x)$ if $0<x<2$

$f_y (y) = 3/8 y^2 $ if $0<y<2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally there is no choosing:$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x,y)\;dy$$
We can substitute $f_{X,Y}=[0<x<y<2]\frac34x$ where $[\text{condition on }x,y]$ is a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ that takes value $1$ if the condition is satisfied and take value $0$ otherwise.

Then for fixed $x$:$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[0<x<y<2]\frac34x\;dy=\frac34x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[0<x<y<2]\;dy$$

Now we discern cases:

If $x\notin(0,2)$ then the integrand is $0$ for every $y$ so that $f_X(x)=0$.

If $x\in(0,2)$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[0<x<y<2]\;dy=\int_x^2dy=2-x$ so that $f(x)=\frac34x(2-x)$.

The first equality is probably the part you label as "choosing which interval".

It rests on the observation that for $y\notin(x,2)$ the integrand is $0$.

---

The same principle works for finding: $$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[0<x<y<2]\frac34x\;dx$$for a fixed $y$.

If $y\notin(0,2)$ then the integrand is $0$ for every $x$ so that $f_Y(y)=0$.

If $y\in(0,2)$ then $f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[0<x<y<2]\frac34x\;dx=\int_0^y\frac34xdx=[\frac38x^2]_0^y=\frac38y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

To get the marginal densities from the joint density, you "integrate out" each variable. In this case, the region $0<x<y<2$ is a triangle. To see this, draw the horizontal boundary lines $x=0$, $y=2$, and $y=x$. The triangle is then the region overlapped by $x>0,y<2, x<y$.

For this region, we see that for a fixed $y$, $x$ varies from $0$ to $y$, hence
$$f_{Y}(y)=\int_{0}^{y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx=\int_{0}^{y}\frac{3}{4}x\ dx=\frac{3}{8}x^{2}\bigg\rvert^{x=y}_{x=0}=\frac{3}{8}y^{2}$$
Similarly, if we fix a value for $x$, $y$ varies from $x$ to $2$
$$f_{X}(x)=\int_{x}^{2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dy=\int_{x}^{2}\frac{3}{4}x\ dy=\frac{3}{4}xy\bigg\rvert^{y=2}_{y=x}=\frac{3}{4}x(2-x)$$

If the region is unclear, draw a picture and it should make more sense.